# Apps hangs on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

My Android app is working perfectly up to Lollipop. But it is hanging in Marshmallow.

When I open the app,back to home button,again open the app. It hangs. I have used all these libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

And i use :

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you have not implement RuntimePermission, set targetSdkVersion 22

Answer (score 0):

What time of exception are you getting?

Check to see if you're requesting any of these permissions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

If you are, then you will have to specifically request them using `requestPermissions`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I have just updated libraries to the latest libraries ie

 `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Since i haven't use dangerous permission i dont need to handle on runtime.